# Umbraco Razor, comparing 2 sets of page ID's in a string for any matches

Tags: string, loops, razor, umbraco, contains

was originally using .Contains() when my 2 comparison items were something like, 
Is:

```
1234
```

In:

```
5555 6732 **1234** 3456
```

And in this case, yes it was, and the code would run on the if(), but when I introduced multiple comparisons, like,

Is:

```
**1234** 2344 2341 3245
```

In:

```
5555 6732 **1234** 3456
```

It no longer works with .Contains(), so I am looking to find out how best to compare the 2 strings for any match, and if **any** block of four numbers is in both strings do X.

The blocks of numbers are currently in one string each, like 'placeIDs' and 'adIDs' with spaces in between each number.

Here is my full code if you prefer to see it:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@using RJP.MultiUrlPicker.Models;
@{
string pagesID = "";
string adPlace = "";
var selection = Umbraco.TypedContent(1384).Children("headerAdvert").Where(x => x.IsVisible() && x.GetPropertyValue<bool>("active"));
    foreach(var item in Model.Content.Ancestors().OrderBy(x => x.Level))
        {
            pagesID = string.Concat(@item.Id.ToString(),"  ",pagesID);
        }
            pagesID = string.Concat(@Model.Content.Id.ToString(),"  ",pagesID);
            @:Page ID's @pagesID
     }

<div id="leaderboard" class="advert-carousel owl-carousel owl-theme" style="opacity: 1; display: block;">
    <div class="owl-wrapper-outer">
<div class="headerSlick owl-wrapper">
    @{
    foreach(var item in selection){
        var dateRange = item.GetPropertyValue<Diplo.DateRangePicker.DateRange>("campaignDate");
        <p>Your date range is from @dateRange.StartDate to @dateRange.EndDate</p>
        var typedMultiNodeTreePicker = item.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("location");
        foreach (var item2 in typedMultiNodeTreePicker)
            {
                adPlace = string.Concat(@item2.Id.ToString(),"  ",adPlace);
            }

        @:ad target ID's @adPlace
        if(item.HasValue("location") && pagesID.Contains(adPlace.ToString())){
        <script>alert("yes")</script>
        var singleLink = item.GetPropertyValue<Link>("links");
            if(singleLink != null)
            {
                if(item.HasValue("wideImage"))
                    {  
                    IPublishedContent mediaItem = item.GetPropertyValue<IPublishedContent>("wideImage");
                        <div class="owl-item" style="width: 891px;"><a href="@singleLink.Url" target="@singleLink.Target">
                            <img class="tag-headadvert img-responsive" style="display: inline;" src="@mediaItem.Url" width="100%" alt="@singleLink.Name" /></a>
                        </div> 
                    }
            }
        }

        else if (item.IsNull("location")){
        var singleLink = item.GetPropertyValue<Link>("links");
            if(singleLink != null)
            {
                if(item.HasValue("wideImage"))
                    {  
                    IPublishedContent mediaItem = item.GetPropertyValue<IPublishedContent>("wideImage");
                       <div class="owl-item" style="width: 891px;"><a href="@singleLink.Url" target="@singleLink.Target"><img class="img-responsive" src="@mediaItem.Url" width="100%" alt="@singleLink.Name" /></a></div> 
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

But in summary, I take the page's ID and all its parent ID's, make them into a string, then I take the Ad Location ID's make them into a string, and im trying to find if one ID exists in the other. I am happy to rework anything, but I am a beginner to this so please be patient. ;-)

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow :)

If you put your strings into an Array, you can run Contains on them.
Since you know your entries are always going to be separated by a space inbetween, you can simply do the following:

```
var allMyAdIds = "1234 2387 1931 2313 8237 2391 3911 2833 9741 1234";
var adIDs = allMyAdIds.Split(' ');
if (adIDs.Contains("1234"))
{
    // DO X
}
```

For multiple Contains, you could do:

```
var targetsToMatch = new[]{"1234", "7851", "9138"};
foreach (var item in targetsToMatch) {
    if (adIDs.Contains(item)) {
        // DO X
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you :-) I am implementing this, but just concerned that where you have put 1234, could have multiples also, should it still work then? Kind of like a "Does anything in this set, match anything in that set"

Comment: I have edited the answer to support multiple targets :) I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks, I apologise ive never used this method before so i do have some confusion looking at it, with your targetsToMatch array, is this to replace my "adPlace = string.Concat(@item2.Id.ToString(),"  ",adPlace);" line, where i merge them all together?

Comment: I have shoe-horned the code together now, in this pastie; https://www.pastiebin.com/5ba2500d62739 But i just need to make that top variable "pagesID" become the source for the array.

Comment: Thanks thats in and working great, ive also realised now in this use-case, I only want it to run the loop once when it has a match, "foreach (var it3m in targetsToMatch) {" Currently I get an output for every match I think? Ideally I just want to run through the array, find 1 or 100 matches, then do something once. Thanks Mikkel youve been a big help.

Comment: Ah i think i can just use a break!